# "Origin" must be supplied issue with the function in r: possibly environment/namespace issue

Tags: r, xts

I have a function that produces the first date of each month:

```
firstDayNextMonth <- function(x)
#
# Wrapper for the function above - applies the firstDayNextMonth to the vector
#
{
  return(as.Date(sapply(x, fDNM)))
}
```

where fDNM is

```
fDNM <- function(x)
#
# Computes the date of the first day of the next month
#
{ 
  if (as.numeric(format(x,format="%m"))==12)
  {
    nextMonth = 1
    Yr = as.numeric(format(x,format="%Y"))+1
  }else{
    nextMonth = as.numeric(format(x,format="%m"))+1
    Yr = as.numeric(format(x,format="%Y"))
  }
  y = as.Date(paste(Yr, nextMonth, '01', sep='-'), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  return(y)
}
```

everything works well when I apply this function to an index. However, when I include this function to a custom package I get

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(sapply(x, fDNM)) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

What could cause this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the Usage section of `?as.Date` has clues if you have learned how to read that section.:

```
## S3 method for class 'character'
as.Date(x, format = "", ...)
## S3 method for class 'numeric'
as.Date(x, origin, ...)
## S3 method for class 'POSIXct'
as.Date(x, tz = "UTC", ...)
```

The 'origin' parameter for `as.Date.numeric` does not have a default value, whereas the method for class character does not have an 'origin' parameter prior to the "dots". You should find that looking at the functions themselves will provide similar confirmation.

Comment: Why would the result of the function differ in the GlobalEnv and in the package namespace?

Comment: I see no evidence of such. The difference is between two different generic versions of the same function name.

Comment: The zoo package includes a as.Date.numeric implementation with a default setting for origin (origin = "1970-01-01"). I guess that user29514 had loaded zoo into his .globalEnv during development time and didn't notice the difference to the base::as.Date.numeric method.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem myself. `as.Date` needs an origin if the field to be converted is numeric.

if you chage you code as below it should work.

```
fDNM <- function(x)
#
# Computes the date of the first day of the next month
#
{ 
  if (as.numeric(format(x,format="%m"))==12)
  {
    nextMonth = 1
    Yr = as.numeric(format(x,format="%Y"))+1
  }else{
    nextMonth = as.numeric(format(x,format="%m"))+1
    Yr = as.numeric(format(x,format="%Y"))
  }
  y = as.Date(as.character(paste(Yr, nextMonth, '01', sep='-')), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  return(y)
}
```

Hope this helps!